# How to change multiple elements property not using class in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple elements which need to change color when anyone of them is clicked. I can't use class for all because class is used for styling. I was using id to get element and change color also but color of first element got changed?

Comment: Your question lacks precision. Consider editing it by adding context, code, etc ... See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: An element can have multiple `class`es. eg. `<p class="class1 class2">Some text</p>`

Comment: you can still add another class to change colour ..

Comment: `I can't use class for all because class is used for styling` classes are used for semantic grouping, not just styling. They are *exactly* what you should use here.

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements can have multiple classes. like `class="red class-click"`

Each `div` below has color(`.red`,`.orange`,`.yellow`) class **and** has class `.class-click` for click listener.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( ".class-click" ).click(function(){
  $(".class-click").css( { backgroundColor : 'black' } );
 });
});
```

```css
div {
 width : 50px;
 height : 50px;
}

.red {
 background-color : red;
}

.orange {
 background-color : orange;
}

.yellow {
 background-color : yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red class-click"></div>
<div class="orange class-click"></div>
<div class="yellow class-click"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#item1, #item2, #item3').click(function(){
    $('#item1, #item2, #item3').css('color', 'red');
});
```